# .htaccess - Block some PDFs on Wordpress site, not all?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pdf

I am using the following .htaccess code for a Wordpress site that includes blocking access to PDFs for all non-logged in users. But I want to be able to allow a couple of PDFs to be publicly available, possibly in another folder if that's the best way to do so. Does anyone know how I can do this, or perhaps to change the code below to only block PDFs from a specific folder?

Thanks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf|doc)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.wordpress_logged_in.$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /access-denied [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't know how important your security is, but I'm pretty sure that anybody can set a cookie in the browser and get your files when you do it like that.

Comment: That's not security. That's at best a minor bump in the road for anyone who wants to get the files. If you want to protect the PDFs, then you put them OUTSIDE of your site's document root and only allow access via scripts that proxy the files for authorized users.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow few pdf by their names like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|doc)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.wordpress_logged_in.$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(allowed1|allowed2)\. /access-denied [NC,R,L]
```